# Proving rationality given

Tags: number-theory

Trying to find a proof that  $(x^n -1)^{1/n}$  is rational/irrational given $x$ is rational and $n>3$. I've tried searching online and in libraries. It's hard to find.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: in the equation $y^n = x^n - 1$ where $x$ and $y$ are rational, multiply by the $n$'th power of a common denominator.  Does Fermat ring a bell?

Comment: Isn't Fermat about integer solutions? I cant make a connection to rationality

Comment: That's why I said multiply by the $n$'th power of a common denominator.

Answer (score 0):

If $x \in \mathbb{Q}$ then $x = p / q$ for some $p, q \in \mathbb{Z}$.
It will boil down to if
$$
\left(\left(\frac{p}{q}\right)^n - 1\right)^{1/n} 
= \frac{r}{s} \iff
\frac{p^n}{q^n} - 1 
= \frac{p^n-q^n}{q^n} 
= \frac{r^n}{s^n}
$$
can be fulfilled by some $r, s \in \mathbb{Z}$ for $n >3$. That means $s=q$ and $r^n = p^n -q^n$, the latter not always possible I believe.

Update: Robert is right, of course, $r^n + q^n = p^n$ is famous for positive $r, q, p$.

Comment: r,q,and p cannot be integers, but can they be rational numbers?